# Using Google Apps Script to check file availability but getting timed out

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout, fetch

I have a spread sheet where A-column is a list of urls for FTP files. I'm trying to build a script that checks if files on this list are available or not. Using **UrlFetchApp.fetch()** to see if there is an error but this approach runs in to *maximum execution times* because missing files causes a big delay.

```
function debug(){
  var files = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
  for(var i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i][0];
    try {
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(file);
    } catch(error) {
      Logger.log(error);
      continue;
    }
    Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  }
}
```

Here is clip from execution transcript

```
14-02-25 14:42:33:156 EET] Starting execution
[14-02-25 14:42:33:169 EET] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:33:209 EET] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.039 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:33:235 EET] Range.getValues() [0.025 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:33:236 EET] Logger.log([ftp://foo.bar/514549.txt.gz, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:34:357 EET] UrlFetchApp.fetch([ftp://foo.bar/514549.txt.gz]) [1.12 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:34:358 EET] HTTPResponse.getResponseCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:34:358 EET] Logger.log([200.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:42:34:358 EET] Logger.log([ftp://foo.bar/302489.txt.gz, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:43:34:350 EET] UrlFetchApp.fetch([ftp://foo.bar/302489.txt.gz]) [59.988 seconds]
[14-02-25 14:43:34:356 EET] Logger.log([Exception: Address unavailable: ftp://foo.bar/302489.txt.gz, []]) [0 seconds]
```

As we can see it takes 60 seconds for UrlFetchApp.fetch() to timeout which makes list of couple unavailable files run in to *"Exceeded maximum execution time"*.

Is there a way to interrupt url fetching sooner or structure some deadline for it?

Comment: @lesto there is no deadline argument or deadline function for UrlFetchApp.fetch(). Not a duplicate.

Comment: sorry, removed duplicated flag, also see response

Answer (score 1):

i'm sorry but you cannot use UrlFetchApp.fetch() to get a FTP file, as the class say it only support HTTP and HTTPS protocol see the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
You add a HTTP interface, on the FTP server or on a bridge server (but then google app would be superflous, i think), still you have no way to deal with timeout